# I keep getting the same "Documentation Beta" badge over and over again

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges

[image]

I'm awarded one every half hour or so. I think I should only have one? I have six so far. They also show up as separate badges on my profile...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We accidentally a clause in the badge SQL. A fix has been deployed and we're about to revoke/re-award the badges, this time correctly.

Comment: I'm unsure as to whether the missing "missed" in your answer is intentional or not...

Comment: @Matt Old memes are best memes. http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/i-accidentally